# sudo prompts for password over ssh

Tags: ssh, sudo

I have sudo set up for a user (myuser) as follows on "hostname" (sudoers content):

```
myuser ALL=(suser) NOPASSWD: /path/script*
```

this works fine, so I can run the following, logged in locally as myuser on hostname, without need for password:

```
sudo -u suser /path/script
```

however, when I use ssh (with keys set up, so no password required) to login and run, as follows:

```
ssh hostname sudo -u suser /path/script
```

I get prompted for a password, and when the password is entered I get:

```
Sorry, user myuser is not allowed to execute '/path/script' as suser on hostname
```

.

**UPDATE**
The problem is solved by removing the "*" from the end of the command in sudoers.
The * was added to allow parameters to be passed to script, but actually doesn't appear to be necessary.
Still don't understand why the * allows the sudo to work locally, but not over ssh.
So question still stands

Comment: Difficult to answer without the content of /etc/sudoers and /etc/ssh/sshd-config but are you sure, ssh is **not** asking for the password?

Comment: I can't see /etc/sudoers, but sudo -l gives the output shown
ssh hostname logs in with no password prompt, so I was assuming that's OK. I don't have /etc/ssh/sshd-config - is there an alternative? and how might it affect this?

Comment: Does reserving a pseudo pty change anything, ie. `ssh -t hostname sudo -u user /path/script`

Comment: no, that doesn't help

Comment: Show us what you can from: `ssh hostname sudo -D9 -u user /path/script`.

Comment: don't have D9 option. Am on RHEL 4.7

Comment: Then whatever debugging flags your `sudo` command supports. `man sudo`.

Comment: I don't see any debugging options for the sudo I have