# Added user as sudoer but still prompted for password after ssh key-based login authentication

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sudo

This [unanswered question](https://superuser.com/questions/442207/sudo-prompts-for-password-over-ssh) is similar to mine except my situation is simpler.  After successfully logging in as user `ubtuntu` with `ssh`, any `sudo` command prompts for the user's password with:

```
[sudo] password for ubuntu:
```

After authenticating with keys, I would like to not have to provide the password for this user.  Is this possible?  All the shells are bash.  Thanks.

The `/etc/sudoers` sudoers file on the remote machine:

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Comment: Did you read the rest of the file?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams thanks, was able to find the info I needed in that previously daunting `man sudoers` entry.  Is the answer I've posted acceptable?  (It works but is there a "better" entry you can use in the `/etc/sudoers` file?)  Thanks.

Comment: This is what sudo does. You need to add NOPASSWD to the file, sudo is meant to prompt for a password if a user is allowed to sudo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `man sudoers` under the heading `User Specification` it says:

> The basic structure of a user specification is `who = where (as_whom)
>   what'.

Under `Tag_Spec` it says:

> NOPASSWD and PASSWD
>
> By default, sudo requires that a user authenticate him or herself before running a command.

Using `visudo` edit the line `%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL` to read:

```
# Allow members of group sudo on any host as any user to execute any command without a password
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the above answer you can actually do (in visudo)

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

That will work if the above gives you any issues